# replace list of characters in a string

Tags: java

I have a String which is the title of a webpage. so it can have < > and other special charecters in them.

I want to write a function that will take a string and replace a list of charecters. Trying to find the best way to do it.

Shoud I use a list or array or enums to hold the list of special charecters or is there something in java that will already do this.

```
filterText(String text, List specialCharecters)

filterText(String text, Array specialCharecters)

filterText(String text, Enum specialCharecters)
```

Comment: Well you need to think in regular expressions to modify this strings.

Comment: Are the characters that should be filtered determined? What are you want to filter exactly? HTML Tags?

Comment: Yes, i know the list of charecters that I want to remove

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str.replaceAll("[<>]", "")`

Put all your special characters between the quotes. This statement is using regular expression, so care about escaping characters that are special for regular expression. For example if you want to replace `(` you should say `str.replaceAll("[\\(]", "")`

Comment: How do I replace list of this chars : ", <,>!,/,? do you know?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class in Apache commons lang API specifically the    [replaceEach](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceEach%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) function