# Indexing confusion after deleting a character in Stringbuilder - Java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

```
public static String RemoveChar(String s,char a,char b)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
        for(int i=0;i < sb.length();i++)
        {
            if(sb.charAt(i)==a || sb.charAt(i)==b)
            {   System.out.println("Characters removed are : "+a+" "+b);
                System.out.println("Removed character at "+i+" : "+s.charAt(i));
                sb.deleteCharAt(i);

            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }



    **Input** :  RemoveChar("beabeefeab",'a','b');
    **Output** : Characters removed are : a b
    Removed character at 0 : b
    Characters removed are : a b //It checks if the character at the index is a or b
    Removed character at 1 : e //after it passes the if condition it removes e.Why does this happen? What alternative can i do for this?
    Characters removed are : a b
    Removed character 6 : f
    ebeefeb
```

I am new to stringbuilder and java so excuse me if this is a silly question.Suggest an alternative and tell me what went wrong here.It would be really helpful for this beginner :)

Comment: when you want to remove characters as you loop it's better to loop from the end to the front e.g.  `for(int i=sb.length()-1;i >= 0 ;i--){...}`

Comment: Based on what you seem to be trying to do, see [Remove all occurrences of char from string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576352) or [replace list of characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8154377)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `deleteCharAt` you delete the character at index `i` which shifts the rest of the characters to the left by one position. So, in this case, you should not increment the index counter `i` by one.

Try this

```
for(int i=0; i < sb.length() ; )
    {
        if(sb.charAt(i)==a || sb.charAt(i)==b)
        {   System.out.println("Characters removed are : "+a+" "+b);
            System.out.println("Removed character at "+i+" : "+sb.charAt(i));
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        } else {
           i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After you delete the character at index `i`, the character that *used* to be in position `i + 1` is now in position `i`, and the character that used to be at `i + 2` is now at `i + 1`.  Afterwards, you increment `i`, so you're looking at the character that used to be in index `i + 2`, and skipped the character at index `i+1`.

Easy solutions include iterating backwards, or doing `i--` inside your `if`.